# How to fix iOS/Xcode build error, undefined symbol `__C.NSURLSession.DataTaskPublisher`?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

When adding a cocoapods dependency, we started getting build errors like these:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "type metadata accessor for (extension in Foundation):__C.NSURLSession.DataTaskPublisher", referenced from:
      (extension in TinyNetworkingObjcIO):__C.NSURLSession.load<A>(TinyNetworkingObjcIO.Endpoint<A>) -> Combine.AnyPublisher<A, Swift.Error> in libTinyNetworkingObjcIO.a(Endpoint.o)
      lazy protocol witness table accessor for type (extension in Foundation):__C.NSURLSession.DataTaskPublisher and conformance (extension in Foundation):__C.NSURLSession.DataTaskPublisher : Combine.Publisher in Foundation in libTinyNetworkingObjcIO.a(Endpoint.o)
  "protocol conformance descriptor for (extension in Foundation):__C.NSURLSession.DataTaskPublisher : Combine.Publisher in Foundation", referenced from:
      lazy protocol witness table accessor for type (extension in Foundation):__C.NSURLSession.DataTaskPublisher and conformance (extension in Foundation):__C.NSURLSession.DataTaskPublisher : Combine.Publisher in Foundation in libTinyNetworkingObjcIO.a(Endpoint.o)
  "(extension in Foundation):__C.NSURLSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: Foundation.URLRequest) -> (extension in Foundation):__C.NSURLSession.DataTaskPublisher", referenced from:
      (extension in TinyNetworkingObjcIO):__C.NSURLSession.load<A>(TinyNetworkingObjcIO.Endpoint<A>) -> Combine.AnyPublisher<A, Swift.Error> in libTinyNetworkingObjcIO.a(Endpoint.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

These errors just appear kind of "out of the blue" after we added a new dependency to our Podfile, with no info about what caused them and what part of the code it originates from, they're just printed after the build and during the linking stage, which now fails.

What does this error mean? What can be done to try and resolve it?

This happens to be a react-native generated XCode project, not sure if that's relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue seemed to be that our project, generated by `react-native init`, had `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` set to the following:

```
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)" "$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)" "$(inherited)"
```

If you generate a plain Xcode project, LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS is not set.

It also turns out that the dependency we added requires Swift 5.1, because it's not binary compatible with older versions of Swift. Which caused breakage, because swift 5.0 was explicitly added to the project by `react-native init` for some reason. Maybe the specific issue here is that the naming conventions for compiled code has changed, and Swift 5.1 expects `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` and not `NSURLSession.DataTaskPublisher`? Who knows..

Simply clearing out `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` so that it's empty, fixed the issue for us. The build works just fine without it in every other aspect.

Related pull request: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29178

Comment: Thank you, this saved me so much time <3

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :) This definitely cost me the better part of a workday... Here's to the obscure unpopular questions on SO that has saved countless thousands of hours around the world!

Comment: Thank you. You saved me. In my case, set like this: `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"  "$(inherited)"`

Comment: Thanks its work for me!!!! 
$(inherited) Remove it